# Best Practice: Should Multiple Wordpress Sites be installed on a single VPS Instance or on individual VPS instances? Pros/Cons?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wordpress

We have a a few dozen Wordpress sites, each with their own domain and database schema. They are running on a single dedicated Linux server currently. We would like to migrate them to their own VPS to isolate them from the rest of our production stack for both security and organizational reasons. Our hosting provider has an option for a single cloud VPS and also has an option for a private VPS Parent in which we could spin up and spin down as many virtual instances as we would need.

My question is for best practices would their be any advantages/disadvantages to either option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was up to me, yes, because then a compromise of one is less likely to affect others.

Pros: limit blast radius, maintenance is isolated, less concern about impacting unrelated customers.

Cons: more expensive (probably), more overhead to manage without infra-as-code, more to monitor.